# NextJS, Strapi, Auth0 on localhost: How can I configure this to work without ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: node.js, next.js, auth0, strapi, caddy

I am developing a web site with the frontend using NextJS, the backend is Strapi and I'd like to use Auth0 as the identity provider.  I have configured Strapi to use Auth0 and this appears to be working.  When I go to `http://localhost:1337/api/connect/auth0` I am provided with the Auth0 custom login screen.  However, when I pass the credentials, I'm returned an `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I have tried to use caddy with the command `caddy reverse-proxy --from :8080 --to :1337`

With that I've updated my server.ts on Strapi to look like this:

```
export default ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  url: env.int('', 'https://localhost:8080'),
  admin: {
    url: '/',
    serveAdminPanel: false,
    auth: {
      secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET'),
    }
  },
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
  webhooks: {
    populateRelations: env.bool('WEBHOOKS_POPULATE_RELATIONS', false),
  },
});


process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

I've updated my url's in the NextJS app to point to 8080 and updated the Auth0 callback URL's the properly accept the correct URLs and I'm still getting the `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you able to access Strapi through https://localhost:8080/ ? if not, you could try: caddy reverse-proxy --from localhost:8080 --to localhost:1337   (with administrator privilege on Windows, it will automatic install root CA - https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#local-https)

Comment: I tried that.  It's in my initial question.  It's at good idea, that's what I keep seeing should be the right answer, but, it isn't working for me.  This is the command I ran: `caddy reverse-proxy --from :8080 --to :1337`

Comment: please try to add localhost in your parameters to caddy, i was failed without it and a root CA installed: `caddy reverse-proxy --from localhost:8080 --to localhost:1337`

Comment: For authorization between Strapi/Next/Auth0, it's more simple to use http instead of https to debug or verify the flow. Move to https after http works, then issues behind would related to SSL setting on Strapi/Next/browers.

Comment: So, my problem was that caddy wasn't configured properly.  I didn't realize that. there was a main Caddyfile to use in a central location.  Once Caddy was configured properly and I updated the redirects, everything started working properly.  For a note, I used Caddy to reverse proxy both my frontend and backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually develop without HTTPS enabled, because then you don't have to worry about SSL issues. When you are done developing, that's when you can switch to HTTPS.

For the development phase I use the following config in my Caddyfile:

```
http://localhost:8080 {
 reverse_proxy localhost:1337
}
```

If you want to use HTTPS anyways during development, you can use

```
localhost:8080 {
 tls internal
 reverse_proxy localhost:1337
}
```

`tls internal` will not work in a production environment so when you are deploying, you can use:

```
example.com {
  reverse_proxy localhost:1137
}
```

This will let Caddy manage the certificates by itself and you can be on your way :)